# Computer Course Subjects

Tags: computer-science

I'm starting a computer course for novice to slightly intermediate users to teach them more about the computer. I am an experienced user. What I'm looking for is topics to discuss. So far, this is what I have:

- Computer parts
- Basic functionalities of Windows Operating System

Still pondering but need ideas in is:

- Microsoft Word and Excel
- Virus Protection
- Internet usage

Anyway, that's what I have thus far. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

Not sure if this question is on-topic, but it's interesting so...

I have delivered training courses to similar groups and would suggest:

1. Computer Maintenance (Correctly installing programs, cleaning your system etc)
2. Beginning Google Search (How to use advanced search techniques)
3. Social Media Starter Guide (If you want to go down this road)
4. Basic Engineering (Cleaning a fan, installing a Memory stick)
5. Security (Recommended anti-virus and how to configure your system for security)

There are a handful I have delivered before. Since they are beginner focused you should be able to deliver whatever you happen to be good at.